# Which Jquery Tool Tip: Modify 'Title' field before displaying

Tags: jquery, tooltip

When I display an image with Fancybox2, I am able to modify the Title field with an afterLoad function to add HTML etc.

I would like to use a a similar facility to show a tooltip after hovering over a thumbnail, because my titles contain more information, than is necessary for a tooltip.

Can anyone advise as to which of the many Jquery tooltips, would be best for achieving this functionality ?

Thanks

mcl

Answer (score 0):

Try [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). It has a good following and works seamlessly across many browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have looked at qTip, but it is not obvious to me, how I can modify the contents of the Title field.  I want to split it on the tilde character and only show the first two splits.  The first one in bold and the second one in italic.